# How to implement the SUS using python 3?

Tags: python

I am using stochastic universal sampling in genetic algorithm. I found the Pseudo code of it. I expose problems in encoding it using Python 3. The error is: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all(). Can anyone help me?

Pseudo Code:

```
SUS(Population, N)
    F := total fitness of Population
    N := number of offspring to keep
    P := distance between the pointers (F/N)
    Start := random number between 0 and P
    Pointers := [Start + i*P | i in [0..(N-1)]]
    return RWS(Population,Pointers)

RWS(Population, Points)
    Keep = []
    for P in Points
        i := 0
        while fitness sum of Population[0..i] < P
            i++
        add Population[i] to Keep
    return Keep
```

My Trial code is as follows:

```
def susSelection(popRanked, eliteSize):

    df = pd.DataFrame(np.array(popRanked), columns=["Index","Fitness"])
    F = df.Fitness.cumsum()
    P = F/eliteSize
    Start = np.random.uniform(0,P)
    Pointers = [Start + i*P for i in range(0,(eliteSize-1))]
    return RWS(popRanked, Pointers)

def RWS(pop, points):
    Keep = []
    for P in points:
        i = 0
        for j in (0,i):
            df = pd.DataFrame(np.array(pop), columns=["Index","Fitness"])
            sumFit = df.Fitness.cumsum()
        if sumFit< P: 
            i+=1
        else: 
            Keep.append(pop[i])
    return Keep
```

Comment: What is your problem? is this throwing an error?

Comment: The error is: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Comment: you should include your error stack trace in your post so that people can help you pinpoint the problem more easily

Comment: Thank you.. Done as you suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used the following code using Python 3. I hope it helps who exposes same problems.

```
def susSelection(popRanked, popSize):

    import copy
    sumFitness = np.cumsum([popRanked[i][1] for i in range(len(popRanked))])
    pointerDistance = sumFitness[len(sumFitness)-1]/popSize

    start = np.random.uniform(0, pointerDistance)

    pointers =[]
    for i in range(popSize):
        pointers.append(start + i*pointerDistance)

    cumulativeFit = 0
    newIndiv = 0
    newPop = [None] * popSize
    nPop=[]
    for i in range(len(pointers)):
        while cumulativeFit <= pointers[i]:
            cumulativeFit += popRanked[newIndiv][1]
            newIndiv += 1
        if (newIndiv>= len(popRanked)-1):
            break
        newPop[i] = copy.deepcopy(popRanked[newIndiv][0])

    for i in range(len(pointers)):
        if newPop[i]!= None:
            nPop.append(newPop[i])

    return nPop
```

Answer (score -1):

This is my implementation , It may be helpful !

```
def make_pointer (pop,n):# n=number of offspring to keep , pop should be sorted !
    F=sum(i.fitness for i in pop) #total fitness of population 
    P=F/n# distance between the pointers 
    start = np.random.random()
    pointers= [start+i*P for i in range(n)]
    return pointers
def select_parents_sus(pop,n ):
    Points=make_pointer (pop,n)
    keep=[]
    for P in Points:
        i=0
        while sum(pop[j].fitness for  j in range(i+1))<P:
            i+=1
        keep.append(pop[i])
    return keep
init_pop=make_init_pop(items,num_of_pop=100)
init_pop = sorted(init_pop, key=operator.attrgetter('fitness'))# note : after each generation you should sort the population by fitness
```

Comment: start in make_pointer should be random.uniform(0, P) and not what u have written.